# Загрузка данных из файла в ListBox

Tags: delphi, файлы, listbox

Есть OpenDialog1, ListBox1, MainMenu1 с обработчиком пункта "Открыть". Нужно, чтобы строки из текстового файла загружались в LsitBox1. Что нужно прописать в обработчике пункта "Открыть", чтобы он считывал строки из файла и поочередно добавлял их в ListBox1?

Пробовал так:

```
if SaveDialog1.Execute then begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;
```

Но в этом случае я получаю только название файла, а мне нужны все строчки текстового файла как отдельные item-ы в ListBox1.

Comment: Нужно посмотреть в хелпе, какой тип у `ListBox1.Items`, и не имеется ли у этого типа метода загрузки из файла.

Comment: Не подскажете, как это сделать? Как найти это в Help?

Comment: Найти класс TListBox, в его списке свойств найти Items, перейти в его описание и далее в описание его типа. Справка может работать криво, можно онлайн  гуглить по запросу вроде `embarcadero tlistbox.items` или начинать с http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Main_Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `Items` имеет тип `TStrings`, у которого, в свою очередь, есть метод для загрузки данных из файла `LoadFromFile`:

```
ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Если кодировка файла совпадает с системной, то её можно не указывать.

Comment: Ну вот - рыбу дал, а не удочку ;-)